# Formatting a column to use a phone number format in EPPlus

Tags: asp.net, excel, vba, vb.net, epplus

I have phone numbers stored as a string of numbers, e.g.: 6028035615, but CAST them as integers when querying. I want to format the data in the cell in proper phone number format, such as (602) 803-5615 as Excel would. But how do I state the format type I want to use?
If I use:

```
  objData.Columns.Add("HPhone", GetType(Integer))
  wshUS.Column(i).Width = 15 ' PhoneH
  wshUS.Column(i).Style.Numberformat.Format = "###-###-####"
```

or

```
 wshUS.Column(i).Style.Numberformat.Format = "(###) ###-####"
```

a blank cell is shown as either -- in the former case or ()- in the latter.
Is there a format type that I can put after the = to get phone numbers as Excel would?
How would I use conditional formatting to overcome that problem?
I am writing in VB.NET in codebehind for web pages.

Answer (score 0):

What is `objData`? Generally speaking, you shouldn't need to add columns to a sheet - EPPlus will do this automatically when your reference the cell for the first time. My VB is a little rusty but this works fine for me:

```
<TestMethod> _
Public Sub PhoneNumberFormatTest()
    Dim file = New FileInfo("c:\temp\temp.xlsx")
    If file.Exists Then
        file.Delete()
    End If

    Dim pck = New ExcelPackage(file)
    Dim workbook = pck.Workbook
    Dim worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("newsheet")

    Const number As String = "6028035615"
    Const format As String = "(###) ###-####"

    Dim startcell = worksheet.Cells(1, 1)

    startcell.Value = Int64.Parse(number)
    startcell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Int64.Parse(number) + 1

    worksheet.Column(1).Width = 15
    worksheet.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = format

    pck.Save()

End Sub
```

I downloaded the source code solution of EPPlus 3 (stable) and ran this as a unit test...

---

**EDIT: Added string manipulation:**

```
<TestMethod> _
Public Sub PhoneNumberFormatTest()
    Dim file = New FileInfo("c:\temp\temp.xlsx")
    If file.Exists Then
        file.Delete()
    End If

    Dim pck = New ExcelPackage(file)
    Dim workbook = pck.Workbook
    Dim worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("newsheet")

    Const number As String = "6028035615"
    Const format As String = "(###) ###-####"

    Dim startcell = worksheet.Cells(1, 1)

    'Directly to numbers with parse
    startcell.Value = Int64.Parse(number)
    startcell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Int64.Parse(number) + 1

    'OR as a string back to a number.
    Dim stringcell = startcell.Offset(2, 0)
    stringcell.Value = number
    stringcell.Value = Int64.Parse(DirectCast(stringcell.Value, String))
    stringcell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "(###) ###-####"

    'As string - does not work as number
    stringcell.Offset(0, 1).Value = number
    stringcell.Offset(0, 1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "(###) ###-####"

    worksheet.Column(1).Width = 15
    worksheet.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = format

    pck.Save()

End Sub
```

Comment: You can ignore the objData part; I realized when going thru the code now I don't need that.

Comment: You can ignore the objData part; I realized when going thru the code now I don't need that. But what is germane is that I am loading the data to the worksheet using a datatable 'wshUS.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(objTable, True)', so your Parse suggestion seems to not apply here. The data for the phone number is read as Integer so it is already a number. In your example what would be produced in the cell if the number string was empty?

Comment: I see what you mean.  See my edit.  I dont think having as a string will work since excel will see it as such (that small error triangle you get in the corner of the cell).  I think you only choice would be to cast it to a number using a loop after it dumps out.  Or changing it in the datatable if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The exact formatting that excel use for phone numbers is: "[<=9999999]###-####;(###) ###-####".

I suggest you also check this answer: [EPPlus Format Cell as "Accounting" Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300428/epplus-format-cell-as-accounting-number). It shows how to get all built-in formatting formula.